Spring Data JPA: Combine ORDER BY in custom query with Sort
Let's say I have a table:



id
title
type




1
health
0


2
sport
1


3
music
null


4
book
null



I want the result ordered by type first that is health -> sport, if it null then delegate for Sort.
Expected results:
If Sort.by("id"):



id
title
type




1
health
0


2
sport
1


3
music
null


4
book
null



If  Sort.by("title")



id
title
type




1
health
0


2
sport
1


4
book
null


3
music
null



I tried to create a custom query, but it's didn't work:
@Query("SELECT p FROM Playlist p ORDER BY p.type")
Page<Playlist> findAll(Sort sort);

Thanks a lot!
